# getElementById não funcionando

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função JS que chama um ajax e passo os parâmetros `(codigo, id_trigger, info1,..., info10)` e passando `info1 = document.getElementById('textTicker').value` ele vira uma string, se eu dou `console.log(info1)` ele me retorna o próprio texto: "document.getElementById('textTicker').value" e não realmente o valor do campo.

Existe alguma forma que consigo pegar esse valor do campo?

```
info1 = "document.getElementById('textTicker').value"; 

function CallAjaxGenerico(codigo, id_trigger, info1, info2, info3, info4, info5, info6, info7, info8, info9, info10){

         $('#'+id_trigger).change(function(){

         $.ajax({

                ...

                data : { 

                      'CODIGO' : codigo, 

                      'INFO1' : document.getElementById(''+id_trigger+'').value, 

                      'INFO2' : info1 
                 } 
          }); 
}
```

e o console.log(info1) retorna "document.getElementById('textTicker').value"

Comment: Teria que mostrar o código porque isso não deveria acontecer em situações normais.

Comment: não coloque as aspas, senão vira uma string mesmo.

Comment: Estou usando uma função php que chama essa função do arquivo js. Nesse arquivo js document.ElementbyId vem como string

Comment: Ok, mas dessa forma o valor de `info1` será sempre a string `document.getElementById('textTicker').value` e não o valor de `#textTicker`.... o JavaScript não executa comandos e métodos dentro de aspas... tudo dentro de aspas é string para o JS

Comment: já tentou utilizar $("#textTicker").val()  ou $("#textTicker").text() ??

Comment: Não coloque código referente à pergunta em comentários. Ao invés disso, edite a pergunte e coloque lá o código, formatando-o com `Ctrl + k` ou com o botão `{}` do editor

Comment: @DanielaT. você vai ter que usar um `eval()` nessa string, é algo bem zoado mas é o que se faz caso precise executar código JS a partir de um texto: https://jsfiddle.net/tbyqy4Lz/ - [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: @Renan usando eval() funcionou! Muito obrigada!

Comment: Não use eval, dúvido muito que justifique o seu caso. Porque não utiliza os selectores de Jquery e pega o valor com `val()`. Aliás você utiliza este método ` $('#'+id_trigger).change(function(){` e depois passa um string? Reveja a sua implementação. Não é crítica é conselho.

Answer (score 1):

Caso você realmente precise que seu `document.getElementById` seja uma *string* e deseje executá-la em seu código, você deve usar o `eval()` no seu *JavaScript*.

```
var teste = 'olha';
eval("console.log(teste)")
```

[Referência](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

[Matéria explicando um poucos sobre os possíveis perigos de utilizar o `eval()`](https://imasters.com.br/front-end/eval-considerado-util-geracao-de-codigo-no-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Na sua situação não faz sentido utilizar o `eval`, aliás o eval deve ser evitado.

Se pretende passar a "referência" de um elemento pode facilmente substituir:

`info1 = "document.getElementById('textTicker').value";`

por:

`info1 = "#textTicker";`

Visto que está utilizar jQuery ficará:

```
info1 = "#textTicker";

function CallAjaxGenerico(codigo, id_trigger, info1, info2, info3, info4, info5, info6, info7, info8, info9, info10){

         $('#'+id_trigger).change(function(){

         $.ajax({

                ...

                data : { 

                      'CODIGO' : codigo, 

                      'INFO1' : $("#"+id_trigger).val(), 

                      'INFO2' : $(info1).val()
                 } 
          }); 
}
```

Também pode pode utilizar  o `querySelector` nativo do javascript para ir buscar um elemento.

Exemplo:

```
var div = "#minhadiv";

var valor = document.querySelector(div).value;
```

Comment: Eu tentei fazer uma função bem genérica e que em alguns casos, pode ser que info1 seja vazio, isso daria problema de referência pra $(" ").val()? esse era meu maior problema de simplesmente passar o id do campo

Comment: Se passar $(" ").val() vai-lhe retornar `undefined`, contudo pode utilizar essa designação para manipular o resultado final. `if (typeof info2 != 'undefined')`

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o seu problema tem a ver com o [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) da página, dando uma olhada no SO, encontrei a seguinte [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13539769), que ao meu ver, é o mesmo caso.. porém, como informei no comentário acima, existe um seletor do Jquery, que basicamente funciona da seguinte forma:

```
$("#meuid")
```

e para acessar o valor:

```
$("#meuid").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o comando:

```
info1 = document.getElementById('textTicker').value;
```

Sem aspas.